# I want to call the string property through the function to the console, see if you can suggest

Tags: javascript, string, function, parameters, console.log

**The console says the value is undefined**

```js
const pc = {
    brandname: "hp",
    modelName: "hp-221Gt",
    cpu: {
        brandname: "hp",
        motherBoard: "inteLiCore",
        raminGB: 4,
        rominGB: 1024,
        processore: "Octacore",
        processorMaxSpeedinGHz: 3.8,
    },
    powerOn: "yes",
    // powerOff : false,
    newPowerStatus: function (on) {
        this.powerOn = on;
        // this.powerOff = off;
    },
    run: function () {
        return this.newPowerStatus(on);
    }
}

console.log(pc);
console.log("The cpu I use has following specs : ", pc.cpu)
console.log("Is the pc running : ", pc.newPowerStatus.on);

var show = "powerOn";

console.log(pc[show])
console.log(pc.run);
```

I tried to call the string value of a property in the console through the function.

Comment: You must use parentheses after a function reference to call the function. `newPowerStatus` should be `newPowerStatus()` (with no `.on` property after it), and `run` should be `run()`

Comment: Bro it still said the same thing undefined.

Comment: Making the changes in the comment result in the value being logged as desired. (`newPowerStatus` doesn't return anything, so its call shouldn't be logged)

Comment: I got you, BTW Thanks for help